# Arduino/C char construction generates trash

Tags: arduino, char, wifi, esp8266

I have the following code (snippet):

```cpp
void readEeprom(){
  int lenPass = int(EEPROM.read(0));
  int lenSsid = int(EEPROM.read(1));
  char password2[lenPass];
  char ssid2[lenSsid];

  for(int i = 0; i < lenPass; i++){
  password2[i] = char(EEPROM.read(i+2)) ;
  Serial.println(password2);  
  };
  Serial.print(":");
  for(int i = 0; i < lenSsid; i++){
  ssid2[i]= char(EEPROM.read(i+lenPass+2));
  Serial.println(ssid2);
  };
  Serial.println("password2: " + String(password2));
  Serial.println("ssid2: " + String(ssid2));
  WiFi.begin(ssid2, password2);
  };
```

It is an Arduino/C code that should read some configurations out of the internal EEPROM and connect to a WiFi (it is an ESP8266-Module (wemos D1 mini)).

However, the reading works as expected, this is what I get through the Serial Console:

```
T
Tk
TkP
TkPw⸮⸮⸮?⸮⸮⸮?$ @⸮⸮⸮?
TkPwm⸮⸮?⸮⸮⸮?$ @⸮⸮⸮?
TkPwmh⸮?⸮⸮⸮?$ @⸮⸮⸮?
TkPwmhu?⸮⸮⸮?$ @⸮⸮⸮?
TkPwmhuj⸮⸮⸮?$ @⸮⸮⸮?
TkPwmhujr⸮⸮?$ @⸮⸮⸮?
TkPwmhujrs⸮?$ @⸮⸮⸮?
TkPwmhujrs$?$ @⸮⸮⸮?
:W
WL
WLA
WLAN⸮⸮⸮?⸮⸮⸮?Pt @TkPwmhujrs$?$ @⸮⸮⸮?
WLAN-⸮⸮?⸮⸮⸮?Pt @TkPwmhujrs$?$ @⸮⸮⸮?
WLAN-U⸮?⸮⸮⸮?Pt @TkPwmhujrs$?$ @⸮⸮⸮?
WLAN-Ul?⸮⸮⸮?Pt @TkPwmhujrs$?$ @⸮⸮⸮?
WLAN-Ull⸮⸮⸮?Pt @TkPwmhujrs$?$ @⸮⸮⸮?
WLAN-Ullr⸮⸮?Pt @TkPwmhujrs$?$ @⸮⸮⸮?
WLAN-Ullri⸮?Pt @TkPwmhujrs$?$ @⸮⸮⸮?
WLAN-Ullric?Pt @TkPwmhujrs$?$ @⸮⸮⸮?
WLAN-UllrichPt @TkPwmhujrs$?$ @⸮⸮⸮?

password2: TkPwmhujrs$?$ @⸮⸮?
ssid2: WLAN-UllrichPt @TkPwmhujrs$?$ @⸮⸮?
```

As you can see, the construction of the `password2` and `ssid2` char array is producing trash and the connection doesn't work.

Can anyone understand and help me with that?

Comment: The funny/weird thing is, when I remove the  `Serial.print(":");`, the Output gets even more f*cked up: it adds those weird characters after the ssid-lines (output lines 12 and following) after the single `W` in line 12 already.
I don't understand that...

Comment: NUL termination?

Comment: 'I need it working until tomorrow' please don't try to push your deadlines onto SO volunteers, it's disrespectful;(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Strings of characters in char arrays in C have to be null terminated so functions like print know where they end.  Right now you set up an array called password2 with some length (you didn't show all the code so who knows).  It gets allocated in memory and is full of whatever junk was left over in those memory locations.  Then you read one character and add to the first slot and tell it to print the whole array.  And what do you see?  You see the one character you added followed by all that junk in the array.  Same thing once you've added the second and third characters and so on.  You have to put a null '\0' at the end of the string to tell the print function where the useful part ends so it doesn't print the entire array but rather just the part you've filled.

```
for(int i = 0; i < lenPass; i++){
  password2[i] = char(EEPROM.read(i+2)) ;
  password2[i+1] = '\0';
  Serial.println(password2);  
  };
```